# Line-height discordant between JQuery and CSS style

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

This is a little part of a game, but the context is not important. In a square div I want to align verticaly a single char. I can try other ways to do that but I want to understand what is wrong in this code.

On the Android emulator all is ok, on my smartphone (HTC M7) the char is more close to the top.

**HTML GENERATED FROM JS**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 23%; height: 23%; left: 0%; top: 0%; font-size: 12.5vw; line-height: 63.75px;">
    <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS - DEFINE SQUARE DIV**

```
#memory-game .card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%; /* THIS IS DINAMICALY RECALUCLATED FROM JS */
    height: 20%; /* THIS IS DINAMICALY RECALUCLATED FROM JS */
    margin: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #9e6186;
    color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.8em; /* THIS IS DINAMICALY RECALUCLATED FROM JS */
    text-align: center;
}

    #memory-game .card:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

**THIS IS A CLICK EVENT ONLY FOR DEBUG**

```
// SET LINE-HEIGHT WORK, IS VISIBLE ON THE INLINE STYLE ATTRIBUTE (image below)
$('#memory-game .card').css('line-height', $('#memory-game .card').height() + 'px');

// DEBUG VALUES
var height = $('#memory-game .card').height();
var lineHeight = $('#memory-game .card').css('line-height');
var style = $('#memory-game .card:first').attr('style');

navigator.notification.alert(
    'height: ' + height + ' / line-height: ' + lineHeight + ' / style: ' + style,   // message
    function () { },                                                                // callback
    'INFO',                                                                         // title
    'close'                                                                         // buttonName
);
```

[image]

JQuery get a line-height of 15% less of the line-height set on the style (with a bigger grid the values of height and line-height it is also less of 15%).

**JQuery return the computed style, and it's fine, in fact JQuery is definitely right! Character is not aligned, but why then? what's wrong ??**

*Thanks*

**EDIT**

This is the DOM inspector on the device... it seems to be a bug, if someone have a better explanation...

[image]

Comment: try using css flexbox

Comment: @charlietfl Probably there are many solutions, but I want to understand why the calculated line-height property does not match that set on the inline style.

Comment: have you set `scale` in meta tag? Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: This is a good intuition, but unfortunately I created the META `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">` for the working example is more hard, but I can try...

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug, a webkit bug caused by font boosting. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186